# Why does `btoa` encoding in javascript works for 20 digit string and not 20 digit int?

Tags: javascript, hash, encoding

Consider the following `btoa` output

```
btoa(99999999999999999999)
"MTAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAw"

btoa(99999999999999999998)
"MTAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAw"

btoa("99999999999999999998")
"OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTg="

btoa("99999999999999999999")
"OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk="
```

We see that `btoa` is unable to encode unique hash for 20 digit `int` but was able to encode 20 digit `string`. Why is this?

My original guess is that since `btoa` is base `64` it can only encode something that is less than base `64`, but why is it capable of encoding a 20 digit `string` instead?

Moreover btoa seems to not able to encode `int` less than `9223372036854775807` which is a `2^63`

```
btoa(9223372036854775302)
"OTIyMzM3MjAzNjg1NDc3NjAwMA=="

btoa(9223372036854775303)
"OTIyMzM3MjAzNjg1NDc3NjAwMA=="
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of floating point imprecision. Remember, JavaScript doesn't have *integers* except temporarily during certain calculations; all JavaScript numbers are IEEE-754 double-precision floating point. `99999999999999999999` is not a safe integer value in IEEE-754 numbers, and in fact if you do this:

```
console.log(99999999999999999999);
```

...you'll see

```
100000000000000000000
```

The max safe integer (e.g., integer that won't be affected by floating point imprecision) is `9007199254740991`.

Since `btoa` accepts a *string* (when you pass it a number, the number just gets converted to string), just put quotes around your value:

```
btoa("99999999999999999999")
=> OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk=
```

Of course, if the value is the result of a math calculation, you can't do that. You'll have to change whatever it is that's calculating such large numbers, as they exceed the precise range of the number type.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, but why is javascript able to encode 20 digit `string` ? Surely 20 digit `string` take more bit than 20 digit `int` as each digit in `string` has more than 10 possibilities

Comment: @Kevin: `btoa` always works on strings. If you pass it anything that isn't a string, the first thing it does is call `toString` on it (in effect). This has nothing to do with `btoa`, it's just the nature of JavaScript numbers: That number isn't held precisely, and when you do things with it (like `toString`), it comes out differently from the literal `99999999999999999999` you started with.

Comment: Ah I see, so base 64 encode is allow to encode string greater than 64 bits? Does the btoa guarantees uniqueness of hash in that case?

Comment: @Kevin: `btoa` doesn't create a "hash," it creates a Base64 encoded version of the string you give it. If you give it something unique, you get back something unique. It's a lossless system. Some reading: http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/window.btoa.html, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64